# ERROR TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable in pyspark data frame of struct

Tags: python, json, pyspark, nested, aws-glue

I have struct PM that contains different "Pr". 
I want to count nbr of distinct elements Pr in the PM STRUCT.

**Code**

```
schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('PM',
        StructType([
            StructField('Pr', StringType(),True),
            StructField('Rd', StringType(),True)
    ])
    ),
    ])
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(data, schema)
print(df.PM.select(F.countDistinct("Pr")))
```

**ERROR**
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

Comment: Adding a sample dataframe would most likely help people to comprehend the problem better.

Comment: @Bitswazsky sorry but my data is confidential. But the data frame contains a struct of pm

Comment: @Bitswazsky original post edited. Please have a look

Comment: I think you need `ArrayType()` [refer](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.types.ArrayType)

Comment: @samkart where can I added please?

Comment: here, refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394717/creating-a-pyspark-schema-involving-an-arraytype)

Comment: or call the column as `df.select(df.PM.Pr)`. So your count statement becomes `df.select(F.countDistinct(df.PM.Pr))`

Comment: @samkart thank you but what I want is just to return an int which represents the countdistinct

Comment: you see what I mean.? @samkart

Comment: `df.select(F.countDistinct(df.PM.Pr)).collect()[0][0]` this should do it. Does it not?

Comment: @samkart no I got this error **IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 57'**

Comment: what did you try till now? Can you include everything in your question?

Comment: Also, post the output of `df.printSchema()` for us to better understand

Comment: @samkart this error that I posted is related to java package . I have fix it with replacing java13 with java11. But got new error here **An error occurred while calling o112.collectToPython. Traceback (most recent call last):An error occurred while calling o112.collectToPython. Traceback (most recent call last):**

Answer (score 0):

something like that :

```
df.select('PM.pr').distinct().count()
```

Comment: Thank you @Steven I tried and got this error **An error occurred while calling o109.count. Traceback (most recent call last):**

Comment: @ceo this is not the error message. The message you posted is "there is an error" ... but we do not have the details we need to resolve it. Give the Traceback.

Comment: Thank you @Steven I tested another function that works perfectly. Thank you